# Can anyone help me understand why my PFUser subclass crashes on save()?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've done the required steps

1. Subclassed PFUser

   ```
   class OYUser: PFUser, PFSubclassing {

       func bio() -> String {

           if self["bio"] != nil {

               return self["bio"] as! String

           } else {

               return ""

           }

       }
   }
   ```
2. I've imported PFObject+Subclass.h in my bridge file
3. I've registered the PFUser subclass in the app delegate before setting app id and publishable key

When I create a new OYUser with signUpInBackgroundWithBlock() it works perfectly but when I call OYUser.currentUser()!.save() after making a change I get a crash with a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

In my experience that usually means I was trying to access an object that was deallocated from memory but when I print the the current user object it is not nil.

Any ideas from those Parse.com users out there?

Comment: Why not: `if let bio = self["bio"] as? String { return bio } else { return "" }` or perhaps `return self["bio"] as? String ?? ""`

Comment: Thanks and yes that does work in creating a better getter but there is still an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on this very object that is not nil. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use optional binding:

```
//if self["bio"] is a non-nil value, it assigns it to the constant bio
//then returns bio, if self["bio"] is nil, then it returns ""
if let bio = self["bio"] as? String {
  return bio
} else {
  return ""
}
```

This won't crash your app, because it will return `""` if `self["bio"]` is nil.